# Flutter inheritance giving normal inheritance results?

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, flutter-test

i have two classes one is a model and one is an entity the model extends the entity:

code for the entity class:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class NumberTrivia extends Equatable {
  final String text;
  final int number;

  const NumberTrivia({
    required this.text,
    required this.number,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [text, number];
}
```

code for the model class:

```
import '../../domain/entities/number_trivia.dart';

class NumberTriviaModel extends NumberTrivia {
  NumberTriviaModel({
    required String text,
    required int number,
  }) : super(
          text: text,
          number: number,
        );

  factory NumberTriviaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NumberTriviaModel(
      text: json['text'],
      number: (json['number'] as num).toInt(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'text': text,
      'number': number,
    };
  }
}
```

and this is how i test the model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:clean_arch_example_offline/features/number_trivia/data/models/number_trivia_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import '../../../../fixtures/fixture_reader.dart';
import '../../domain/entities/number_trivia.dart';

void main() {
  final tNumberTriviaModel = NumberTriviaModel(number: 1, text: 'Test Text');

  test(
    'should be a subclass of NumberTrivia entity',
    () async {
      expect(tNumberTriviaModel, isA<NumberTrivia>());
    },
  );
}
```

and for some reason it gives me this error instead of passing:

```
Expected: <Instance of 'NumberTrivia'>
  Actual: NumberTriviaModel:<NumberTriviaModel(Test Text, 1)>
   Which: is not an instance of 'NumberTrivia'
```

what is wrong here and how can i fix it?

Comment: It seems suspicious that your test does `import '../../domain/entities/number_trivia.dart';` instead of `import 'package:clean_arch_example_offline/features/number_trivia/domain/entities/number_trivia.dart';`.  That makes me suspect that you accidentally have multiple `NumberTrivia` classes in multiple files.

Comment: yes that was the solution i had `NumberTrivia` in the test folder by accident.

Answer (score -1):

Create a mock class by extending Mock and implementing your original class ..